# iOS unlocking an object on notification using GCD

Tags: ios, notifications, grand-central-dispatch

Say I create an object `myObject` and at some point I want it locked until I receive a notification. After I receive the notification I'd like to unlock it. Can this be accomplished   using GCD or do I have to use locks or something? Thanks!

Edit:
So here's the exact problem I'm trying to solve.
I've got a thread that's writing photos to the `ALAssetsLibrary`.
The UI is working with `ALAssets` to display photos from the library.
My problem is this: `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum` changes the library causing all the `ALAssets` to be invalidated, so if my second thread is in the middle of loading a photo from the library it might fail (and often does). I read that the only way to fix this is to load after the `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification`, so I'm trying to make the library inaccessible from the moment I write to it to the moment I receive the notification.

Comment: What do you mean by locking and unlocking here? If you just want to disable functionality, can't you just use a simple boolean property?

Comment: Yes please add clarification and some code. Are you waiting for an asynchronous call back for example? Or do you just want to disable functionality based on a flag as Brad suggests?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my app I'm trying to lock the ALAssetsLibrary because I'm simultaneously reading and writing to it (on two separate threads..) and what happens is, when I write an image I have to wait for the ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification before I try getting an image from it (otherwise assets seem to invalidate while I'm trying to get them out). The idea was to somehow lock the library while writing and unlock when I get the notification.. Is there any normal way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about the problem in terms of locks, when you should be thinking about it in terms of queues. What you want to do is something like this (untested), given some shared "Resource". It's just a sketch of the approach, but it should get you on the right track. You should avoid locks whenever possible.

```
@implementation Resource

- (id)init {
...
  // Assuming you are the only one who can possibly change the library
  // See suspendQueue for related code
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                          selector:@(resumeQueue:) ...
                                              name:...thenoteification...];

// Always request things synchronously on the queue
- (Something *)somethingForStuff:(Stuff *)stuff {
  __block Something *result;
  dispatch_sync(self.queue, ^{
    result = GetSomethingForStuffFromMe(stuff);
  });
  return result;
}

// Always change things asynchronously on the queue with a barrier
// And in your case, suspend the queue to lock it until done
- (void)setSomething:(Something *)something forStuff:(Stuff *)stuff {
  dispatch_barrier_async(self.queue, ^{
    SetSomethingForStuff(something, stuff);
    [self suspendQueue];
  });
}

// You'll need to think this through a little bit. It depends on your exact model.
// I'm using isSuspended really just as an error-check to make sure something
// hasn't gone wrong.
- (void)suspendQueue {
  NSAssert(! self.isSuspended, @"In this example, I don't allow recursive suspension.");
  [self.queue suspend];
  self.suspended = YES;
}

// This code assumes you're the only one who can cause this notification.
// You may need to change things a little if that's not true
- (void)resumeQueue {
  NSAssert(self.isSuspended, @"We should only ever see this notification if we caused it");
  self.suspended = NO;
  [self.queue resume];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't even know you can suspend a queue :D This makes sense :)

Comment: I've got one question though.. If I suspend a queue could there be a problem with one block still being run? If for example on a block from queue Q1 I decide to suspend queue Q2, I don't want any blocks from Q2 to be running (I'd like to wait till the one that's running is finished). Will this still work?

Comment: Suspending prevents any new blocks from being scheduled (it has no impact on currently running blocks). Using dispatch_barrier_async() means that the provided block must run alone. So since the suspend happens within the barrier, we know that no other blocks could be running or will run. So to your specific question, if Q1 suspends Q2, then all the running blocks will finish.